# Easiest way to repair charset and collation on a mysql database?

Tags: mysql, unicode, collation

Because mysql default settings are not quite Unicode friendly it can happen quite often to endup with a database with broken charset.

Usually you just want to reconfigure it to use `utf8` character set and `utf8_unicode_ci` collation.

Which is the easiest command to do this for a given database?

Warning: do not post links to untested scripts, I tested at least 5 of them (written in bash/perl/php/python) and they all failed to repair a database where the collation was set correctly at database and table level but not at column level.

Comment: Are you looking for a script to change table and column collations, or do you need to repair the data as well?

Comment: Do you simply want to change the charset/collation of each `*TEXT` and `*CHAR` column to `utf8`/`utf8_unicode_ci`?

Comment: For the moment I will assume that the data can be converter properly to UTF8, meaning that the database text content is not corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to write a solution myself and published to:

https://gist.github.com/1068021

Notes:

- `mysqldump` is borken, even if tell it to not include CHARSET it will include them if it i set at column level.
- this solution does not assume a default charset at mysql-server level so it set it at database level and resets it to defaults for table and column level.

Feed free to post bugs or patches, I will try to solve them fast.